# Mouse movement capture

Tags: c#, mouse

I have an application wich open a modal form with the ShowDialog method.
Once this form is displayed I want to capture the mouse movement even if the cursor is outside the form.
How can I capture the mouse movement? I saw something with the Capture property but I cannot manage to make it work.

[edit]

I want to be notified if the mouse move outside the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Capture` property is the correct way, but there are some limitations.

- Only the foreground window can capture the mouse
- Mouse capturing can be disabled by other parts of the system
- The Win32 API function `SetCapture` gets reset everytime a "mouse up" event occours. I assume that also applies for .NET.

See the [remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.capture.aspx) of `Capture` property.

When the mouse is captured, you'll receive the usual events but with a wider mouse coordinate range (for example a negative X position, if the mouse is left of the capturing control)

Mouse capturing is fragile, because of it's global nature. Check if there are other ways to handle certain events. Perhaps the `MouseLeave` or `MouseEnter` events are enough in your case.

Comment: The capture is done only if the cursor is hover one of the application form but this is ok for me.
I set Capture after the Load event.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the static property [Control.MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can read the position of the cursor, using the Cursor.Position property, see [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx)