# auto resize of window with mouse movement

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I have the following app that has 3 buttons. 1 allows me to open a new window where I can resize this window to that I want, and then press button 2 to capture a picture of that window size. My question is how can I make it so that when i press button 1 it will show Form2 but then the Form2 window will move with the mouse and when i click and drag for the size then release it takes that region like this here
[image]

This is what it currently looks like and I have to manually resize the window 
[image]

**Form1.vb**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim bounds As Rectangle
        Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim graph As Graphics

        bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
        screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Form2.Bounds.Width, Form2.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
        graph.CopyFromScreen(Form2.Bounds.X, Form2.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

        PictureBox1.Image = screenshot
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End Sub
```

**Form2.vb**

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am not sure that it's possible easily like that. See, if you have form #2 on top of #1, and assuming #1 is background (black, opacity = 50%), and #2 is moving, you cannot undarken form #1, you can only make it even darker with form #2's opacity. So how did you plan to work it out?

Comment: @Neolisk hmm ok well it possible to keep the current solution but make form window form2 use mouse events to follow the pointer when you click down and drag? rather than manually resizing it?

Comment: Do you mean have only 1 form with opacity 50% (reverse the selection)? So you selected area will be showing in dark and the rest is regular?

Comment: @Neolisk yes thats what i mean

Comment: See my answer, hope it sets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two methods:

1. [Mouse capture answer @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14191878/897326). This is basically [a link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171545%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426327/mouse-movement-capture).

   > The Capture property of the Control class specifies whether a control has captured the mouse. To determine when a control loses mouse capture, handle the MouseCaptureChanged event.
2. [How to capture mouse position outside of a form?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/88d9b5ed-42b7-4d80-a770-96b6800616e3/how-to-capture-mouse-position-outside-of-a-form?forum=winforms)

Comment: I suspect that the OP is going to have to send WM_SIZING messages to Form2 in order to get a smooth resize.

Comment: @ConradFrix: if smoothness is a concern, I'd go with DirectX (DirectDraw and DirectInput). You can then paint your active desktop onto the form, and draw a capture rectangle any way you like.