# How to Switch to another form after seconds time interval using C# Windows Form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I tried searching this problem online and got this code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = 10000;
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyTimer.Stop();
       this.Hide();
        frm_Start frm_Start = new frm_Start();
        frm_Start.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }
```

this is working but my problem is when I use other forms, it also closes after 10secs.

What I imagine is like, when you leave a specific form for 10 seconds I want it to switch to the main form.  Just for that specific form and not all the forms.

Comment: The other forms would only close after 10 seconds if you added that Timer code to every form. If you don't want the other forms to close after 10 seconds, remove that code from those forms?  The description is confusing, and I might be misinterpreting what you're after here. "What I imagine is like, when you leave a specific form for 10 seconds I want it to switch to the main form. Just for that specific form and not all the forms."  Do you mean if you don't use that form for 10 seconds then it will automatically switch back to the main form?...

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to automatically switch forms? It sounds kind of user hostile to me. You might want to consider posting your idea to https://ux.stackexchange.com/ before going into the technical details.

Comment: @Idle_Mind yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "leaving" a form? Do you mean when it loses focus (ie the user opens their email) you want the main form to show up and take user focus after X seconds?
Or do you mean when you close Form2, you want FormMain to be made visible (essentially you have multiple forms but only want 1 to be visible at a time)?

Comment: You could do [something like this PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20553330/2330053) implementing IMessageFilter.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be to pass a parameter when initializing Form #2 to indicate that that form should NOT have the timer running.

For example, if this is your Form #2's constructor currently:

```
public frm_Start() {
    Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
    MyTimer.Interval = 10000;
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Start();
}

private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer.Stop();
   this.Hide();
    frm_Start frm_Start = new frm_Start();
    frm_Start.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Then, change the constructor to accept a boolean flag, that when set to false, would disable initialization of the timer, like so:

```
public frm_Start(bool startTimer) {

    if (startTimer == true){

        Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = 10000;
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
        MyTimer.Start();

    }
}

// never called, since MyTimer is never initialized
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTimer.Stop();
   this.Hide();
    frm_Start frm_Start = new frm_Start();
    frm_Start.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```